# .xsd is not a part of this compilation - Error

Tags: xml, maven, grails, jaxb, xsd

I was trying to run up the OpenADR 2.0 VTN Server.
I've cloned the required files described by this [Link](http://open.enernoc.com/code/)

```
git clone https://github.com/EnerNOC/oadr2-vtn-new.git
git clone https://github.com/EnerNOC/oadr2-ven.git
```

After the cloning process, I followed the steps given in this [Link](https://github.com/EnerNOC/oadr2-vtn-new)
I changed to my oadr2-ven directory and entered the mvn install command

```
cd oadr2-ven
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

After some processes,  I got this error

```
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/Users/Naveen%20Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/binding/oadr20a.xjb.xml{22,60}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Naveen%20Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/binding/oadr20a.xjb.xml; lineNumber: 22; col
umnNumber: 60; "file:/C:/Users/Naveen%2520Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/schema/2.0a/oadr_ei_20a.xsd" is not a part of this compilation. Is this
 a mistake for "file:/C:/Users/Naveen%20Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/schema/2.0a/oadr_ei_20a.xsd"?
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:610)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:604)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:258)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:387)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:143)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:105)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.transform(DOMForest.java:452)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.buildDOMForest(ModelLoader.java:343)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:375)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:172)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:118)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.loadModel(XJC22Mojo.java:45)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:35)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:22)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:271)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/Users/Naveen%20Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/binding/oadr20a.xjb.xml{89,62}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Naveen%20Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/binding/oadr20a.xjb.xml; lineNumber: 89; col
umnNumber: 62; "file:/C:/Users/Naveen%2520Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/schema/2.0a/oadr_emix_20a.xsd" is not a part of this compilation. Is th
is a mistake for "file:/C:/Users/Naveen%20Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/schema/2.0a/oadr_emix_20a.xsd"?
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:610)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:604)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:258)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:387)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:143)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:105)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.transform(DOMForest.java:452)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.buildDOMForest(ModelLoader.java:343)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:375)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:172)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:118)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.loadModel(XJC22Mojo.java:45)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:35)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:22)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:271)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/Users/Naveen%20Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/binding/oadr20a.xjb.xml{95,62}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Naveen%20Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/binding/oadr20a.xjb.xml; lineNumber: 95; col
umnNumber: 62; "file:/C:/Users/Naveen%2520Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/schema/2.0a/oadr_strm_20a.xsd" is not a part of this compilation. Is th
is a mistake for "file:/C:/Users/Naveen%20Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/schema/2.0a/oadr_strm_20a.xsd"?
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:610)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:604)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:258)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:387)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:143)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:105)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.transform(DOMForest.java:452)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.buildDOMForest(ModelLoader.java:343)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:375)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:172)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:118)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.loadModel(XJC22Mojo.java:45)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:35)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:22)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:271)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/Users/Naveen%20Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/binding/oadr20a.xjb.xml{106,62}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Naveen%20Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/binding/oadr20a.xjb.xml; lineNumber: 106; co
lumnNumber: 62; "file:/C:/Users/Naveen%2520Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/schema/2.0a/oadr_xcal_20a.xsd" is not a part of this compilation. Is t
his a mistake for "file:/C:/Users/Naveen%20Kumar/Desktop/oadr2-ven/oadr2-model/src/main/resources/schema/2.0a/oadr_xcal_20a.xsd"?
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:610)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:604)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:258)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:387)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:143)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:105)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.transform(DOMForest.java:452)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.buildDOMForest(ModelLoader.java:343)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:375)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:172)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:118)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.loadModel(XJC22Mojo.java:45)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:35)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:22)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:271)
        at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to parse input schema(s). Error messages should have been provided.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4 seconds
```

What I done is, I simple go to the binding location oadr2-ven\oadr2-model\src\main\resources\binding, and commented the entire binding tag which was showing as error. After that, executing the mvn install works fine, and the build process is successful.

But when I'm running the grails app in oadr2-vtn-new folder, it shows the error as cannot import certain files. This is due to the fact, I commented those lines in oadr2-ven where the appropriate binding is given for those missing files. So the problem is with my oadr2-ven which is the basic necessity for oadr2-vtn-new grails app to run. I dont know how to solve this problem. After some long googlish process, I'm blank.

This is my binding .xml files present in oadr2-ven\oadr2-model\src\main\resources\binding

oadr20a.xjb.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        xmlns:hj="http://hyperjaxb3.jvnet.org/ejb/schemas/customizations"
        xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
        extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" 
                version="2.1">

    <!-- See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html
         for documentation on customizing JAXB bindings
          -->

  <globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"> 
    <xjc:simple />
    <serializable uid="1" /> 
  </globalBindings> 


    <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0a/oadr_ei_20a.xsd">

        <!--
        <hj:persistence>
            <hj:default-generated-id name="Hjid" transient="true">
                <orm:column name="Hjid"/>
            </hj:default-generated-id>
        </hj:persistence>
        -->

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='QualifiedEventIDType']">
            <class name="QualifiedEventID"/>
        </bindings>                     

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='IntervalType']">
            <class name="Interval"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='currentValueType']">
            <class name="CurrentValue"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='ResponseCodeType']">
            <class name="ResponseCode"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='eiEventType']">
            <class name="EiEvent"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='eventDescriptorType']">
            <class name="EventDescriptor"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='eiActivePeriodType']">
            <class name="EiActivePeriod"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='eiEventSignalsType']">
            <class name="EiEventSignals"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='eiTargetType']">
            <class name="EiTarget"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='signalPayloadType']">
            <class name="SignalPayload"/>
        </bindings>

        <!-- Seems there is a bug that prevents JAXB from changing the class 
          name for these enumerated types...
        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='EventStatusEnumeratedType']">
            <class name="EventStatus"/>
        </bindings>
        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='ResponseCodeType']">
            <class name="ResponseCode"/>
        </bindings>
        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='SignalTypeEnumeratedType']">
            <class name="SignalType"/>
        </bindings>
        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='OptTypeType']">
            <class name="OptType"/>
        </bindings>
         -->
    </bindings>

    <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0a/oadr_emix_20a.xsd">    
        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='MarketContextType']">
            <class name="MarketContext"/>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>

    <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0a/oadr_strm_20a.xsd">

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='StreamPayloadBaseType']">
            <class name="StreamPayloadBase"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='StreamBaseType']">
            <class name="StreamBase"/>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>

    <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0a/oadr_xcal_20a.xsd">
        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='DateTimeType']">
            <class name="DateTime"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='DurationValueType']">
            <class name="DurationValue"/>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

oadr20b.xjb.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
        extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" 
                version="1.0">

    <!-- See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html
         for documentation on customizing JAXB bindings
          -->

  <globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"> 
    <xjc:simple />
    <serializable uid="1" /> 
  </globalBindings> 

  <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0b/oadr_20b.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.enernoc.open.oadr2.model.v20b" />         
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>

    <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0b/oadr_ei_20b.xsd">
      <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.enernoc.open.oadr2.model.v20b.ei" />         
      </schemaBindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='QualifiedEventIDType']">
            <class name="QualifiedEventID"/>
        </bindings>                     

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='IntervalType']">
            <class name="Interval"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='currentValueType']">
            <class name="CurrentValue"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='ResponseCodeType']">
            <class name="ResponseCode"/>    
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='eiEventType']">
            <class name="EiEvent"/>      
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='eventDescriptorType']">
            <class name="EventDescriptor"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='eiActivePeriodType']">
            <class name="EiActivePeriod"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='eiEventSignalsType']">
            <class name="EiEventSignals"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='EiTargetType']">
            <class name="EiTarget"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='signalPayloadType']">
            <class name="SignalPayload"/>
        </bindings>
        <!-- Seems there is a bug that prevents JAXB from changing the class 
          name for these enumerated types...
        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='EventStatusEnumeratedType']">
            <class name="EventStatus"/>
        </bindings>
        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='ResponseCodeType']">
            <class name="ResponseCode"/>
        </bindings>
        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='SignalTypeEnumeratedType']">
            <class name="SignalType"/>
        </bindings>
        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='OptTypeType']">
            <class name="OptType"/>
        </bindings>
         -->
    </bindings>

    <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0b/oadr_emix_20b.xsd">    
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.enernoc.open.oadr2.model.v20b.emix" />
    </schemaBindings>
      <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='MarketContextType']">
            <class name="MarketContext"/>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>

    <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0b/oadr_strm_20b.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
        <package name="com.enernoc.open.oadr2.model.v20b.strm" />
    </schemaBindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='StreamPayloadBaseType']">
            <class name="StreamPayloadBase"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='StreamBaseType']">
            <class name="StreamBase"/>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>

    <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0b/oadr_xcal_20b.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>  
      <package name="com.enernoc.open.oadr2.model.v20b.xcal" />
    </schemaBindings>
        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='DateTimeType']">
            <class name="DateTime"/>
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='DurationValueType']">
            <class name="DurationValue"/>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>

  <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0b/oadr_atom.xsd">
     <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.enernoc.open.oadr2.model.v20b.atom" />
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0b/oadr_gml_20b.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.enernoc.open.oadr2.model.v20b.gml" />
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0b/oadr_greenbutton.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.enernoc.open.oadr2.model.v20b.greenbutton" />
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0b/oadr_power_20b.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.enernoc.open.oadr2.model.v20b.power" />
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0b/oadr_pyld_20b.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.enernoc.open.oadr2.model.v20b.pyld" />
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0b/oadr_siscale_20b.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.enernoc.open.oadr2.model.v20b.siscale" />
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0b/oadr_xml.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.enernoc.open.oadr2.model.v20b.xml" />
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0b/oadr_xmldsig.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.enernoc.open.oadr2.model.v20b.xmldsig" />
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0b/oadr_xmldsig11.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.enernoc.open.oadr2.model.v20b.xmldsig11" />
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/2.0b/oadr_ISO_ISO3AlphaCurrencyCode_20100407.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.enernoc.open.oadr2.model.v20b.currency" />
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

I'm new to maven and Grails, I can't figure out what the problem was.

My maven version : apache-maven-2.2.1
My grails version : grails-2.2.2

Comment: You using both bindings file but you processing all XSDs defined within binding file? (oadr_xcal_20a.xsd, oadr_strm_20a.xsd, oadr_emix_20a.xsd, oadr_ei_20a.xsd). Anyway remember that global binding should be once for context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put it in some folder which does not have spaces in it. It seems to be a URL encoding problem between `Naveen%2520Kumar` and `Naveen%20Kumar`.

I remember I have fixed a similar problem in [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin), but probably this Grail plugin does not contain a similar fix.

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem at last. I didn't noticed it that much accurately. Cloned t directly to C: and it works fine.